# Include file includes itself with guards

Tags: c++, include, include-guards

I have two header files, `animation.h` and `hero.h`,
here is the code for `animation.h`:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "hero.h"

#ifndef ANIMATION
#define ANIMATION

//Class

#endif
```

And for `hero.h`:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "animation.h"

#ifndef HERO
#define HERO

//Class

#endif
```

I get the error message `#include file "" includes itself` even when using include guards.
I am new to using include guards and such so this may be a very trivial mistake.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why does animation include hero? I think that a hero requires animation, but animation wouldn't know about hero or any other animated entity. So you should include hero in the cpp file where it is needed, instead of animation (like hero.cpp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the header guards before anything else.

On `gcc` and `MSC`you can also use

```
#pragma once
```

instead. Probably also on other more modern compilers. Simpliy put this at the top of your include, instead of the `#ifdef...`.

`animation.h`

```
#ifndef ANIMATION
#define ANIMATION

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "hero.h"

//Class

#endif
```

`hero.h`

```
#ifndef HERO
#define HERO

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "animation.h"

//Class

#endif
```

Or `animation.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "hero.h"

//Class
```

Comment: That might remove the warning and the immediate problem, but it won’t fix the real problem.

Comment: And note that labeling `#pragma once` “modern” doesn’t make it work. There are situations (for example, source files stored on multiple network servers) where the compiler might not be able to tell whether two include files are “the same” file.